# How to make automaticly scroll to the nav-active in react js

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have problem my tabs scroll cannot scroll go to the last props item. 
Example :

i have 8 index tabs, when i click the last index i got the active index but not scrolled to my last index so i must manually scroll to my last index.

here my tabs.js

```
import Link from 'next/link'
import { string } from 'prop-types'

const orderTab = (props) => (
    <React.Fragment>
        <div className="nav-fixed scrollmenu col-xl-12 p-0 border-bottom pt-sm-2">
            <Link href="/a" as="/a">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" className={props.selectedMenu=='a' ? "nav-active font-weight-bold aa" : "text-muted"}>A</a>
            </Link>
            <Link href="/b" as="/b">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" className={props.selectedMenu=='b' ? "nav-active font-weight-bold aa" : "text-muted"}>B</a>
            </Link>
            <Link href="/c" as="/c">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" className={props.selectedMenu=='c' ? "nav-active font-weight-bold aa" : "text-muted"}>c</a>
            </Link>
            <Link href="/d" as="/d">
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" className={props.selectedMenu=='d' ? " nav-active font-weight-bold aa" : "text-muted"}>d</a>
            </Link>
        </div>
    </React.Fragment>
)

orderTab.propTypes = {
    selectedMenu: string
}

export default orderTab
```

here my css

```
div.scrollmenu {
    direction: ltr;
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

div.scrollmenu a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

here my ilustration output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24NIJ.png)

Comment: How can you click Tab20, if it is not visible in the first place?

Comment: with manually horizontal scroll bro, my case is after i clicked the tab20 the scrolled not automaticly to see tab20 i must manually scroll to the right